# What are better ways to insert element in sorted array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, insert, sorting

I've recently send my CV to one company that was hiring PHP developers. They send me back a task to solve, to mesure if I'm experienced enough.

The task goes like that:

> You have an array with 10k unique elements, sorted descendant. Write function that generates this array and next write three different functions which inserts new element into array, in the way that after insert array still will be sorted descendant. Write some code to measure speed of those functions. You can't use PHP sorting functions.

So I've wrote function to generate array and four functions to insert new element to array.

```
/********** Generating array (because use of range() was to simple :)): *************/

function generateSortedArray($start = 300000, $elementsNum = 10000, $dev = 30){
    $arr = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <= $elementsNum; $i++){
        $rand = mt_rand(1, $dev);
        $start -= $rand;
        $arr[] = $start; 
    }
    return $arr;
}

/********************** Four insert functions: **************************/

// for loop, and array copying
function insert1(&$arr, $elem){
    if(empty($arr)){
        $arr[] = $elem;
        return true;
    }
    $c = count($arr);
    $lastIndex = $c - 1;
    $tmp = array();
    $inserted = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
        if(!$inserted && $arr[$i] <= $elem){
            $tmp[] = $elem;
            $inserted = true;
        }
        $tmp[] = $arr[$i];
        if($lastIndex == $i && !$inserted) $tmp[] = $elem;
    }
    $arr = $tmp;
    return true;
}

// new element inserted at the end of array 
// and moved up until correct place
function insert2(&$arr, $elem){
    $c = count($arr);
    array_push($arr, $elem);
    for($i = $c; $i > 0; $i--){
        if($arr[$i - 1] >= $arr[$i]) break;
        $tmp = $arr[$i - 1];
        $arr[$i - 1] = $arr[$i];
        $arr[$i] = $tmp;
    }
    return true;
}

// binary search for correct place + array_splice() to insert element
function insert3(&$arr, $elem){
    $startIndex = 0;
    $stopIndex = count($arr) - 1;
    $middle = 0;
    while($startIndex < $stopIndex){
        $middle = ceil(($stopIndex + $startIndex) / 2);
        if($elem > $arr[$middle]){
            $stopIndex = $middle - 1;
        }else if($elem <= $arr[$middle]){
            $startIndex = $middle;
        }
    }
    $offset = $elem >= $arr[$startIndex] ? $startIndex : $startIndex + 1; 
    array_splice($arr, $offset, 0, array($elem));
}

// for loop to find correct place + array_splice() to insert
function insert4(&$arr, $elem){
    $c = count($arr);
    $inserted = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++){
        if($elem >= $arr[$i]){
            array_splice($arr, $i, 0, array($elem));
            $inserted = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$inserted) $arr[] = $elem;
    return true;
}

/*********************** Speed tests: *************************/

// check if array is sorted descending
function checkIfArrayCorrect($arr, $expectedCount = null){
    $c = count($arr);
    if(isset($expectedCount) && $c != $expectedCount) return false;
    $correct = true;
    for($i = 0; $i < $c - 1; $i++){
        if(!isset($arr[$i + 1]) || $arr[$i] < $arr[$i + 1]){
            $correct = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $correct;
}
// claculates microtimetime diff
function timeDiff($startTime){
    $diff = microtime(true) - $startTime;
    return $diff;
}
// prints formatted execution time info
function showTime($func, $time){
    printf("Execution time of %s(): %01.7f s\n", $func, $time);
}
// generated elements num
$elementsNum = 10000;
// generate starting point
$start = 300000;
// generated elements random range    1 - $dev
$dev = 50;


echo "Generating array with descending order, $elementsNum elements, begining from $start\n";
$startTime = microtime(true);
$arr = generateSortedArray($start, $elementsNum, $dev);
showTime('generateSortedArray', timeDiff($startTime));

$step = 2;
echo "Generating second array using range range(), $elementsNum elements, begining from $start, step $step\n";
$startTime = microtime(true);
$arr2 = range($start, $start - $elementsNum * $step, $step);
showTime('range', timeDiff($startTime));

echo "Checking if array is correct\n";
$startTime = microtime(true);
$sorted = checkIfArrayCorrect($arr, $elementsNum);
showTime('checkIfArrayCorrect', timeDiff($startTime));

if(!$sorted) die("Array is not in descending order!\n");
echo "Array OK\n";

$toInsert = array();

// number of elements to insert from every range
$randElementNum = 20;

// some ranges of elements to insert near begining, middle and end of generated array
// start value => end value
$ranges = array(
    300000 => 280000,
    160000 => 140000,
    30000 => 0,
);
foreach($ranges as $from => $to){
    $values = array();
    echo "Generating $randElementNum random elements from range [$from - $to] to insert\n";
    while(count($values) < $randElementNum){
        $values[mt_rand($from, $to)] = 1;
    }
    $toInsert = array_merge($toInsert, array_keys($values));
}
// some elements to insert on begining and end of array
array_push($toInsert, 310000);
array_push($toInsert, -1000);

echo "Generated elements: \n";
for($i = 0; $i < count($toInsert); $i++){
    if($i > 0 && $i % 5 == 0) echo "\n";
    printf("%8d, ", $toInsert[$i]);
    if($i == count($toInsert) - 1) echo "\n";
}
// functions to test
$toTest = array('insert1' => null, 'insert2' => null, 'insert3' => null, 'insert4' => null);
foreach($toTest as $func => &$time){
    echo "\n\n================== Testing speed of $func() ======================\n\n";
    $tmpArr = $arr;
    $startTime = microtime(true);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($toInsert); $i++){
        $func($tmpArr, $toInsert[$i]);
    }
    $time = timeDiff($startTime, 'checkIfArraySorted');
    showTime($func, $time);
    echo "Checking if after using $func() array is still correct: \n";
    if(!checkIfArrayCorrect($tmpArr, count($arr) + count($toInsert))){
        echo "Array INCORRECT!\n\n";
    }else{
        echo "Array OK!\n\n";
    }
    echo "Few elements from begining of array:\n";
    print_r(array_slice($tmpArr, 0, 5));

    echo "Few elements from end of array:\n";
    print_r(array_slice($tmpArr, -5));

    //echo "\n================== Finished testing $func() ======================\n\n";
}
echo "\n\n================== Functions time summary    ======================\n\n";
print_r($toTest);
```

Results can be found here: http://ideone.com/1xQ3T

Unfortunately I was rated only 13 points out of 30 for this task (don't know how it was calculated or what exactly was taken in account). I can only assume that's because there are better ways to insert new element into sorted array in PHP. I'm searching this topic for some time now but couldn't find anything good. Maby you know of better approach or some articles about that topic?

Btw on my localhost (PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch, AMD Athlon(tm) II X4 620) `insert2()` is fastest, but on ideone (PHP 5.2.11) `insert3()` is fastest. 
Any ideas why? I suppose that array_splice() is tuned up somehow :).

**//EDIT**

Yesterday I thought about it again, and figured out the better way to do inserts. If you only need sorted structure and a way to iterate over it and your primary concern is the speed of insert operation, than the best choise would be using SplMaxHeap class. In SplMaxHeap class inserts are damn fast :) I've modified my script to show how fast inserts are. Code is here: http://ideone.com/vfX98 (ideone has php 5.2 so there won't be SplMaxHeap class)

On my localhost I get results like that:

```
================== Functions time summary  ======================

           insert1() => 0.5983521938
           insert2() => 0.2605950832
           insert3() => 0.3288729191
           insert4() => 0.3288729191
SplMaxHeap::insert() => 0.0000801086
```

Comment: You could use binary search to find the place where to insert a new element. After that just use `for` to shift the elemtns with one temporary variable (that would store the current item). O(N) in the worst case and minimal (1 numeric variable) memory overhead

Comment: @zerkms I'm already using binary search in `insert3()`. Not much faster because `array_splice()` seems to be not optimized much.

Comment: and that probably is the most efficient way of doing that. I assume you lost your points because of just overengineering

Comment: In php7 there is `ds` extension for data structures https://github.com/php-ds . Here is article how to use it and some benchmarks: https://medium.com/@rtheunissen/efficient-data-structures-for-php-7-9dda7af674cd#.odvifz3xl

Comment: Why the binary search insert method is not quite fast than the others?!?! (except the SplMaxHeap)

Answer (score 4):

It may just be me, but maybe they were looking for readability and maintainability as well?

I mean, you're naming your variables `$arr`, and `$c` and `$middle`, without even bothering to place proper documentation.

Example:

```
/**
 * generateSortedArray()    Function to generate a descending sorted array
 *
 * @param int $start        Beginning with this number
 * @param int $elementsNum  Number of elements in array
 * @param int $dev          Maximum difference between elements
 * @return array            Sorted descending array.
 */
function generateSortedArray($start = 300000, $elementsNum = 10000, $dev = 30) {
    $arr = array();                             #Variable definition
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $elementsNum; $i++) {    
        $rand = mt_rand(1, $dev);               #Generate a random number
        $start -= $rand;                        #Substract from initial value
        $arr[] = $start;                        #Push to array
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Comment: Code is not so complicated in my opinion. Some for loops with `array_splice()`, binary search etc. `$arr` is quite obvious i think :). In my email to them I've wrote that if they need better documentation I can add some more comments to my code and send them new version :) but maby i should do this at the begining...

Comment: I would even say that the function is **too** confusing for just generating data sample. `range()` would be enough.

Comment: @zerkms I've also send them info (in comments to that function), that I could simply use range() (its 2 tims faster) but values won't be random (and it's not fun :)). Now when I think of it, it didn't matter if they were random or not :)

Comment: If randomness is not an issue, the easiest solution would be `range()` followed by `array_reverse()`. (Edit, since randomness is irrelevant.)

Comment: @fruchtose They didn't said exactly that they want random elements. But they also said that I should write function to generate array. It was obvious to me that using range() would be little weird since it's not my function :) and writing my own range() was simply waste of time :)

Comment: @piotrekkr: overcomplicating is a habit opposite to oversimplifying. In my personal experience I prefer to write the cleanest and the simplest possible solutions, and make them more complex only in case it is required and proven that it is necessary

Comment: @zerkms I agree that simplest solutions are best. I would use `range()` if they wouldn't ask for my function to generate array. Maby I misunderstood them in some way.

Comment: Back to the topic, anyone have ideas about better approach to insert element to sorted array?:)

Comment: @piotrekkr: doubtfully you could do that better than for `O(N)`. I could also add the element in the end of the existing array and resort it. It may give some profit to some sorting algorithms that rely much on the initial state

Comment: @piotrekkr: Also, I would argue that passing the array as reference is not a good practice. One should take the array as an argument, and return a new array with the inserted item in it. Then one would call it as `$arr = insert1($arr, 43621);` for example.

Comment: @Truth they wanted functions that insert new element into generated array (at least what I understoos from task description). I suppose that there was a reason that array was 10k elements long, so it would not be so efficient to copy it.

Comment: Maybe they were probably trying to get you to implement your own binary heap. Binary trees can be stored in regular arrays. A requirement of a binary heap instance called the *heap property* is that *all nodes are either [greater than or equal to] or [less than or equal to] each of its children, according to a comparison predicate defined for the heap*. Since your array is *all* sorted and not just regarding children in relation to parents (which are at child1=2*parentIndex and 2*parentIndex+1), it is a already a binary heap! Only issue is that it wouldn't be complete sorted after insertion...